# Ajax Get, not sending parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax

So, I'm trying to make a get request with ajax to a page, however it doesn't seem to be sending the parameters... I echoed out all get parameters by doing print_r($_GET); It prints them out when I go to the page, but not when I use ajax... I'm really not sure what's happening.

```
var num1 = $("#number1").val();
var num2 = $("#number2").val();
var num3 = $("#number3").val();
var num4 = $("#number4").val();
var num5 = $("#number5").val();
var num6 = $("#number6").val();

$.get("page.php", {number1: num1, number2: num2, number3: num3, number4: num4, number5: num5, number6: num6}, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

It isn't erroring, I feel like its something to do with the way the data is but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Comment: Why do you say "it doesn't seem to be sending"? Can't you validate what it's sending?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put an ID on the number elements... I thought it would give me an undefined error though... Oh well. I've sorted it :)